# New site hook not working on WP multisite

Tags: wordpress

I was just assigned to an ongoing project at my job, wherein I had to set it up so a few options were automatically set when a new site was created. I found the 'wpmu_new_site' hook, and created a local multisite install, writing up a brief script that essentially worked as such:

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'update_blogOptions');

function update_blogOptions($blogID) {
    // Do actions
}
```

On the local install, this worked as expected.

When I moved the code to the active project, it does nothing. I even replaced all the code in the body of the function with just an error log, but it did nothing.

Any advice if I'm using the right hook? Why it may be working on one site and not the other? Things I can look at to look for conflict?

Comment: How exactly are you using this code?

Comment: Not sure I follow brasofilo. I have it in a general actions/filters file (all other actions in the file are working), and in the code was just a few update_site_option.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/wp-multisite-adding-pages-on-blog-creation-by-default